# JPA 2.0 Provider Hibernate 3.6 for DB2 v9.5 type 2 driver is throwing exception in configuration prepration

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, db2, jpa-2.0

The JPA 2.0 Provider Hibernate is throwing exception while preparing configuration for entity manager factory, I am using DB2 v9.5 database and DB2 v9.5 JDBC type 2 driver .

```
java.sql.SQLException: [IBM][JDBC Driver] CLI0626E  getDatabaseMajorVersion is not supported in this version of DB2 JDBC 2.0 driver.
 at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.throwNotSupportedByDB2(Unknown Source)
 at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:117)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2833)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2829)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1840)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:48)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:32)
```

Comment: Can you confirm the JDBC version and type of the driver? It seems like you are mixing "type" and "version". DB2 is well tested with JDBC driver Type 4 (100% Java) and JDBC 3.0+. Please, provide the output for the following command: `java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code:  there is an undocumented `hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` property, setting it to `false` may help if you can't change JDBC driver:

```
<property name = "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value = "false" />
```

Comment: Thanx, Found this hibernate experimental code; these experimental code makes open source unworkable without source code.

Comment: can you let us know what exactly this property does as far as hibernate is concerned?

Comment: @SibzTer: It disables the call of the offending method. I didn't examined it thoroughly, take a look at the source of `SettingsFactory`.