# Hibernate Unable to lookup JNDI name exception

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, nhibernate-mapping, tomcat6, hibernate-4.x

Please suggest me any configuration changes required or any suggestions welcome

---

When i tested same code with hibernate 4.3.8 and tomcat 6.0 :

I'm testing with one bean and one table, got the Unable to lookup JNDI name exception as below

**Found the below exception: when i debug with hibernate 4.3.8 source code, 
lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/db2]**

```
Throwable occurred: javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/db2]
    at com.application.Servlet.init(Servlet.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Apr 2, 2015 9:38:47 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
```

I googled it and found it is issue with tomcat 6.0 and fixed in the 6.0.36 version. But found the below exception:

When i tested hibernate 4.3.8 with 6.0.36 got the below exception:

I'm testing with one bean and one table, got the exception nullpointer as below
root cause is dialect getting null value (i have debug with hibernate 4.3.8 source code).

```
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at com.application.HibernateSessionFactory.<init>(HibernateSessionFactory.java:53)
    at com.application.HibernateSessionFactory.newInstance(HibernateSessionFactory.java:82)
    at com.application.Servlet.init(Servlet.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

My hibernate configuration :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">     
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Freightliner DB2 version uses different identity SQL than built-in Hibernate DB2 dialects  -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

my session factory creation code:

```
sessionFactory =new Configuration()
                    .configure("/hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true")).buildSessionFactory();
```

---

Got the below exception when debugging for the above error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [IBM][JDBC Driver] CLI0626E  getDatabaseMajorVersion is not supported in this version of DB2 JDBC 2.0 driver.
 at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.SQLExceptionGenerator.throwNotSupportedByDB2(Unknown Source)
 at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(Unknown Source)
```

---

The above exception removed after adding below property:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

In hibernate 4.3.8 reading like below property,

```
final boolean useJdbcMetadata = ConfigurationHelper.getBoolean( "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", configValues, true );
```

so we should mention the above mentioned property.

The below links helped me to identify the fix:
[JPA 2.0 Provider Hibernate 3.6 for DB2 v9.5 type 2 driver is throwing exception in configuration prepration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593136/jpa-2-0-provider-hibernate-3-6-for-db2-v9-5-type-2-driver-is-throwing-exception)

Comment: After debug i have found the below error, which is causing the problem:

**  [IBM][JDBC Driver] CLI0626E  getDatabaseMajorVersion is not supported in this version of DB2 JDBC 2.0 driver. **

Comment: The above exception removed after adding below property:

<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>


final boolean useJdbcMetadata = ConfigurationHelper.getBoolean( "hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", configValues, true );